# Trouble zipping all files in a directory?

Tags: php

I am trying to zip up files in a directory, but keep getting the following error:

Warning: ZipArchive::addFile() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tags\download.php

My code is as below:

```
opendir($dir);
$listfiles = scandir($dir);

        $files = array($listfiles);

        $zipname = 'newzip.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $zip->addFile($file);
        }
        $zip->close();
```

What I am trying to do is open a directory, add all the files into an array ($listfiles), then add the files in the array into a zip folder. I can see the files are being stored in the array by using vardump, so I can't see where the issue lies (maybe I'm taking a completely wrong route to achieve this?)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Well, it could be something to do with you providing an `array` as a parameter where the method is expectin a path, which is a `string`. Track your code back to see where `$file` comes from. Hint: `scandir()` returns an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you have is that you actually have an array within an array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php
According to the documentation, scandir() returns an array of files.

You then proceed to add that array into another array  when you do
$files = array($listfiles);

the structure for your array now looks like [ [file,file,file ] ]

When you reach the for loop, it only loops once, receiving that 0 index which is actually an array, hence the error.

Solution:
remove the array($filelist);

Answer (score 0):

```
opendir($dir);
$listfiles = scandir($dir);
$files = array($listfiles); // this is why.
```

`scandir()` already returns an array, I don't know why you're wrapping another array around it, but that's your problem.